# heroku worker job java playframework

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-1.x, worker

After reading all the articles I could not find a solution to my problem.

1. I have a java play web-app running good on Heroku. With a web: xxx process in the Procfile
2. In the same app, I have defined some Jobs.

   - I have MyJob class which extends play.Job
   - I have a Main class while(true) wait and execute MyJob.

my Procfile looks like this.

```
web:    play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
worker: java -cp target/classes;target/dependency/* jobs.MyJob
```

I understand that since this is not a maven project classes and dependency directories dont exists.

But then, how shall I set the worker: `java xxxx command`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you annotating your Job classes? To start a job when Play starts, just do:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {
```

Or use the @Every or @On annotations:

```
@On("0 0 12 * * ?")
public class Bootstrap extends Job {

@Every("1h")
public class Bootstrap extends Job {
```

Answer (score 0):

Play! Jobs run inside web app. 
If you want to use them on your heroku app - it will be better to just embed them into your web app, without starting a dedicated worker. With this you can have only web dyno on heroku.

Just annotate your jobs with `@OnApplicationStart` and they will be run with the application.